# Why does this error appear during compilation?(CodeWars)

Tags: c++, linux, memory-corruption

Here below is the error that ocuurs after the compilation. I've been solving 5kyu task on CodeWars.I passed all test cases, but when I want to attempt, these errors pop up:

```
double free or corruption (out)
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==1==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7f64918f2a10 bp 0x7fff85a912b0 sp 0x7fff85a91060 T1)
==1==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==1==Hint: address points to the zero page.
==1==WARNING: invalid path to external symbolizer!
==1==WARNING: Failed to use and restart external symbolizer!
    #0 0x7f64918f2a0f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x40a0f)
    #1 0x7f649193b966  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x89966)
    #2 0x7f64919429d9  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x909d9)
    #3 0x7f6491949f69  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x97f69)
    #4 0x429a0a  (/workspace/test+0x429a0a)
    #5 0x426f0e  (/workspace/test+0x426f0e)
    #6 0x426a17  (/workspace/test+0x426a17)
    #7 0x42661b  (/workspace/test+0x42661b)
    #8 0x42d8e5  (/workspace/test+0x42d8e5)
    #9 0x425ccd  (/workspace/test+0x425ccd)
    #10 0x7f64918d3bf6  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21bf6)
    #11 0x404619  (/workspace/test+0x404619)

UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==1==ABORTING
```

MY CODE IS:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;


string interpreter(const string &code,const string &tape){
    string str_1 = ">";
    string str_2 = "<";
    string str_3 = "*";
    string str_4 = "[";
    string str_5 = "]";
    string str_6 = "0";
    string str_7 = "1";
    string copy_code;copy_code=code;
    string result;result=tape;
    int step = 0;
    for(unsigned long i=0;i<copy_code.size();++i){
        if(str_1==string(1,copy_code[i]))step++;
        if(str_2==string(1,copy_code[i]))step--;
        if(str_3==string(1,copy_code[i])){
            //flip(result[step])step=0;}
            if(result[step] == str_6[0]){
                result[step] = str_7[0];
            }else {
                result[step] = str_6[0];
            }
        }
    }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: That's a runtime error, not during compilation of the code.

Comment: FWIW, `string copy_code;copy_code=code;` can just be `string copy_code = code;`

Comment: Smells like an out of bounds error.

Comment: You're probably going out of bounds at one of these `result[step]`. Check what the value of `step` is before doing that.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  i changed my code a bit, and now i get the error like this:should_return_the_final_state_of_the_tape_immediately_if_the_pointer_ever_goes_out_of_bounds. Expected: equal to "1110"
Actual: "1000"